# Let $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}[L,R].$ Let $Y=cX+d,$ where $c>0.$ Prove that $Y\sim\operatorname{Uniform}[cL+d,cR+d]$

Tags: probability, statistics

My attempt:

If $Y=cX+d,$ then $X= (Y-d)/c,$ since $c>0.$

Then $(Y-d)/c \sim \operatorname{Uniform}[L,R],$ since $c>0.$

Isolating for $Y$ gets you 
$L \le (Y-d)/c \le R,$ since $c>0.$

```
cL <= Y-d <= cR 
cL + d <= Y <= cR+d 
Y ~ Uniform[cL+d,cR+d] 

Y ~ Uniform[(-1)0+1,(-1)1+1] 
Y ~ Uniform[1, 0] 
1 <= -X+1 <= 0 
0 <= -X <= -1 
0 <= X <= 1 
X ~ Uniform[0,1] 

Y = 1-X ~ Uniform[0,1] 
cX + d = 1-X ~ Uniform[0,1] 
X ~ Uniform[0,1] = 1 - (cX + d) 
X ~ Uniform[0,1] = 1- cX - d 
X ~ Uniform[0,1] = 1 + X - 1 
X ~ Uniform[0,1] = X
```

Is all this correct?

Comment: This was quite a jumble as posted. I tried to put it into MathJaX, but there are no English words connecting equations and relationships, so I finished by spacing it out and presenting it as text to be more readable. Please re-edit to make it more clear. If you were a student in my class and turned it in for hwk, it wouldn't get much credit without some narrative.

Comment: If $c<0$ and $L<R$ then $cL+d>cR+d$ hence what is $[cL+d,cR+d]$?

Comment: You need $[cR+d, cL+d]$ rather than $[cL+d, cR+d]. \qquad$

Comment: My Mistake, it is c>0

Comment: Then the CDF approach works like a charm, doesn't it? What, you didn't *try* it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the moment generator function.

If $X\sim U(L,R)$, then the moment generator function of $X$ i
s

$$
M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=\frac{e^{tR}-e^{tL}}{t(R-L)}
$$

Then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
M_Y(t)&=\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{t(cX+d)}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[e^{(tc)X}e^{td}]=e^{td}\mathbb{E}[e^{(tc)X}]\\
&=e^{td}\frac{e^{tcR}-e^{tcL}}{tc(R-L)}\\
&=\frac{e^{t(cR+d)}-e^{t(cL+d)}}{t[(cR+d)-(cL+d)]}
\end{aligned}
$$
Which is the moment generating function of a random variable $U(cL+d,cR+d)$. Therefore, if $X\sim U(L,R)$ then $d+cX=Y\sim U(cL+d,cR+d)$.